# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre match_parent y fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

Antes de la llegada del `match_parent` yo usaba mucho el `fill_parent` para definir el ancho total de la `view`. No entendí muy bien porque el equipo de desarrollo de Android pasó a sustituir el uno por el otro. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el `match_parent` y el `fill_parent`? ¿Por qué el `fill_parent` fue reemplazado por `match_parent`?

Comment: Actualmente debes evitar usar "fill_parent"  ya que este valor es marcado obsoleto como menciona WebServeis. La razón del cambio es la malinterpretación de "fill_parent" por eso el cambio a "match_parent" como comenta D. Joel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No hay diferencia marcada entre los dos, ambos se usan para definir que el tamaño del componente *(View)*  sea tan grande como el padre. Solo fue renombrado a partir de la `API 8` `fill_parent`  por `match_parent`.

> ¿Por qué el fill_parent fue reemplazado por match_parent?

El equipo de `Android` encontró que los desarrolladores estaban malinterpretando `FILL_PARENT` , Esto es  que un `View` podría llenar *(fill)* el espacio restante del elemento padre. Es por eso que la constante se renombró `MATCH_PARENT` para aclarar su uso.

**[Referencia](http://www.randomlytyping.com/blog/2014/2/9/matchparent-vs-fillparent)**

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia es que `fill_parent` esta catalogada como obsoleta mejor usar `match_parent`

Comment: Gracias per respuesta, más eso para mí debería entrar como comentario y no como respuesta.

Comment: si pero es que no hay más digamos si se quiere cerrar alguna respuesta debe tener no?

Comment: Considero que ambas respuestas son correctas, esta por ejemplo indica la "diferencia",  que en realidad es el nombre y lo que comenta webserveis en su respuesta.